# Is it possible to find the right server by spending less time?

Tags: php, curl

I have a little code to find the right server. About it: there is a large array with links to the server. There is only one valid server (or none at all). The script goes through them in a loop, finds the right one, shifting and checking the HTTP code (valid `200`, invalid `400`).

Code:

```
$r = false;
$urls = ['url1', 'url2', /* ... */];

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($urls); $i++)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urls[$i]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $f = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!curl_errno($ch))
    {
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($http_code === 200) {
            $r = true;
            echo $f;
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}

if ($r === false) return 'not found';
```

And the problem is that the servers give out huge json data and the script slows down and it takes a lot of time. Are there any alternative approaches for finding the right server, in order to save time?

Comment: Try sending and OPTIONS request instead. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36738955/978055

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *the right server*?

Comment: @NigelRen, the server where the HTTP code is 200.

Comment: @Alex or just simply `HEAD`

Comment: @NigelRen isn't that duplicate about checking if a server is up? This one seems more about discriminating by HTTP status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, 
[What is the easiest way to use the HEAD command of HTTP in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545432/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-use-the-head-command-of-http-in-php)

you will get HTTP Response Code without BODY. It will save time

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, my bad.